# Currency Formatting C++

Tags: c++, string

So I am trying to create a program that will take a value from the user and convert it to currency formatting (US: $ ). I seem to be almost there, the only issue I am having is that when I input a value without a decimal, it does not format it with the commas.  How can I change his function so that it will format it no matter if there is a decimal point or not.

```
void dollarFormat(string &currency)
{
    int decimal;
    decimal = currency.find('.'); // Find decimal point
    if (decimal > 3) // Insert commas
    {
        for (int x = decimal - 3; x > 0; x -= 3)
            currency.insert(x, ",");
    }
    currency.insert(0, "$"); // Insert dollar sign
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a test for [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

```
void dollarFormat(std::string &currency)
{
    auto decimal = currency.find('.');  // find decimal point
    if(decimal == std::string::npos)    // no decimal point
        decimal = currency.length();    
    if (decimal > 3) // Insert commas
    {
        for (auto x = decimal - 3; x > 0; x -= 3)
            currency.insert(x, ",");
    }
    currency.insert(0, "$"); // Insert dollar sign
}
```

Side note: to make your code portable, make sure you use [`std::string::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#Member_types) as the type of `decimal` instead of `int`. Or, even better, use `auto` type deduction:

```
auto decimal = currency.find('.');
```

Comment: My professor keeps claiming that using the 'auto' keyword is malpractice and should be avoided?

Comment: @ElSpiffy NO NO NO and again NO. This is one of the example where the usage of `auto` is HIGHLY recommended. It is not altogether malpractice. Ask her/him how he can assign a lambda to a variable, `auto l = [](){std::cout << "use auto";};` without `auto`. And ask her/him to read [this](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/).

Comment: Well, for this part of code I will not change it but I will keep it in mind whenever I have another class. This professor is very against using the std:: method as well. So that why I use namespace std; at the top of my code. How would I change std :: string:: npos to the format my professor is okay with.

Comment: @ElSpiffy I suggest you switch the course to a different instructor ;) `using namespace std;` is in general not recommended, due to name clashes, ADL issues and lots of other pains in real world code. Regarding `std::string::npos`, just use `string::npos` instead (if you already are `using namespace std;`).

Comment: Is it possible to make this function accept a string array?

Comment: @ElSpiffy Write another function for that, which uses this function. The code will be clearer this way.